# How to do a system(“pause”) without printing "Press enter to continue..."?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I am looking for an option that does the same thing as `system("pause")`, but not print the `"Press enter to continue..."` on the screen.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [**`getchar()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x198c66c.aspx).

It will wait for the user to input a character, just like `system("pause")`, but without printing anything.